# What is the RequiresValidationContext property of ValidationAttribute class for?

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, data-annotations, .net-4.5

With .NET Framework 4.5, the [`ValidationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679227.aspx) class now has a new `Boolean` property named [`RequiresValidationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.requiresvalidationcontext.aspx).

I have been digging for long time now and I couldn't find what this property is there for. The difault value for this is false and I initially thought that if this is set to false, the below method is called:

```
public virtual bool IsValid(object value)
```

If it is set to true, then the below one is called:

```
protected virtual ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext);
```

It turns out that no matter what you set, the `IsValid` method which returns `ValidationResult` is always called.

For the love of God, what is this `RequiresValidationContext` property for?

Answer (score 6):

The RequiresValidationContext is useful for validator like CompareAttribute or custom attribute.

ValidationAttribute is abstract class and it depends what implementation you mean. For example I have Validation Attribute that check that some fields are required only if another property has some value.

It depends on Attribute implementation if the IsValid(object value) is called or not. For example:

```
[Display(Name = "Your employer")]
[LoginTypeRequired(LoginType = LoginType.Employee, ErrorMessage = "Employee must fill in Employer.")]
public int? Employer { get; set; }
```

Attribute code:

```
public class LoginTypeRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
     public override bool RequiresValidationContext
     {
          get {return true;} 
     }

     public LoginType LoginType { get; set; }

     protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
          RegisterModel model = (RegisterModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

          if (LoginType != model.LoginType)
              return null;
          else
              return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
      }

       public override bool IsValid(object value)
       {
          return base.IsValid(value);
        }
}
```

The first method with two parameters use  IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) to do the job with the context. If it is everything alright, it call the base and the internal .NET 4.5 stack is:

> LinqDataModel.dll!LinqDataModel.Models.LoginTypeRequiredAttribute.IsValid(object
>   value) Line 92    C# 
>     System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll!System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(object
>   value, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext
>   validationContext) + 0x74 bytes
>
> > LinqDataModel.dll!LinqDataModel.Models.LoginTypeRequiredAttribute.IsValid(object
> >     value, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext) Line 87 + 0xe bytes    C# 
> >       System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll!System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(object
> >     value, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext) + 0x1e bytes
> >       System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate.MoveNext()
> >     + 0xa2 bytes      System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidator.CompositeModelValidator.Validate.MoveNext()
> >     + 0x138 bytes     System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext
> >     controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
> >     + 0x212 bytes

So, you can see that the case IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) is calling IsValid(object value) if not override.

But still you have the chance to override IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) and not to call the base.

Comment: Very clever! But I have to note that your approach works even when `RequiresValidationContext` and `IsValid(object)` aren't overridden.

Comment: Why override `IsValid(object value)` with nothing but a call to the base implementation?

Answer (score 0):

IF I recall correctly, if the [Validate(Object, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679256.aspx) overload rather than [Validate(Object, ValidationContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411784.aspx) is called, it throws a [ValidationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationexception.aspx).